# JAVA Thread animation

Tags: java

I am trying to create simple animation which paints some jlabels in a panel.I am having a button and next to it, a panel. In the panel i am adding labels using the run() method and then remove it. That's what i want to happen every time the button is clicked, but i am getting "java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException".

```
public class Animation extends JPanel implements Runnable{
JLabel l1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom1.png"));
JLabel l2 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom2.png"));
JLabel l3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom3.png"));
JLabel l4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom4.png"));
JLabel l5 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tom5.png"));
static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton buton = new JButton("BUTTON!!!! ");
static Thread t ;

public Animation(){
    add(buton);
    add(panel);     
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
    buton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            removeAll();
            add(buton);
            panel.removeAll();
            //Thread x = new Thread(new Animation()); Also tried this but it paints only 1 label.
            //x.start();
            t.start();
            add(panel);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
        }
    });
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(new Animation());
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}



public void run(){

    System.out.println("paint");
    panel.add(l1);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.add(l2);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.add(l3);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.add(l4);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    panel.add(l5);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("remove");
    remove(panel);
    repaint();
    revalidate();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

}

Comment: NB OP, have you ever heard of *arrays*?

Comment: the same as with *loops* - if you want to create 5 similar labels, you usually just create an array or list and do the process through a loop; otherwise you're creating an obfuscated code, violating the StackOverflow MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) contract.

Comment: I have some serious doubts that you will want `panel` and `t` to be static, as the class appears to be named as a class that is reused.

Comment: @vaxquis its not the same label. Every single label is different.

Comment: nope, every single label is *not* different - learn about inheritance, OOP and data structure aggregation. Every single label *is* the instance of the same class - even more, in your particular case you instantiate them in the exactly the same way. Your coding style is just, well, *wrong*. You should either subclass or do the instantiation/declaration in an aggregated way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are starting the thread twice, which is why you are getting IllegalStateException.  Create a new instance of the Thread class for each run() like this:

```
Thread x = new Thread(Animation.this); 
x.start();
```

You were passing a new instance of Animation when creating a Thread which is why you couldn't see the results. The code above calls run() of the same instance instead.

Comment: What can i do to rerun the run() method ?

Comment: You should make a new instance of the Thread and call start on that like you are trying to do in the commented out section.

Comment: You want the animation to loop? Wrap the body of the `run()` function in a `while(true)` loop. There seems to be a few other issues with the code, but that will get you started, if I understood you.

Comment: @JuliaLeder Thanks ! So "Animation.this" calls the curent instance ?

Comment: Yes, "this" is used to refer to the current instance of the class.  In this case, "this" would refer to the instance of your inner anonymous ActionListener().  This is why you need "this.Animation", which is used to refer to the outer class instance.